# How can I determine which SSL client certificate a connection is using in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, ssl, https, mod-perl, client-certificates

I am writing a web service in Perl that will run under SSL (HTTPS) with client certificates. 
How can I determine which certificate is being used by the client in the current connection so I can filter out unwanted ones?

Note: the web service is being run as a mod_perl script.

Comment: Will this be a cgi or mod_perl script or are you going to open the listening server socket yourself?

Comment: it will be a mod_perl script. I was thinking about using SOAP::WSDL::Server::Mod_Perl2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/):

Use the [Apache::SSLLookup module](http://search.cpan.org/~geoff/Apache-SSLLookup-2.00_04/SSLLookup.pm)

```
  sub handler {
    my $r = Apache::SSLLookup->new(shift);
    my $request_is_over_ssl = $r->is_https;
    my $certificate = $r->lookup_var('SSL_CLIENT_CERT');

    ...
  }
```

mod_ssl environment reference [here](http://eregie.premier-ministre.gouv.fr/manual/mod/mod_ssl/ssl_reference.html#ToC25).